# Running Flask from IPython raises SystemExit

Tags: python, flask, ipython, jupyter

I am trying to run my Flask application from IPython. However, it fails with a `SystemExit` error.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Running this with IPython shows the following error:

```
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-bfd7690b11d8> in <module>()
     17 
     18 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 19    app.run(debug = True)

/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.pyc in run(self, host, port, debug, **options)
    770         options.setdefault('use_debugger', self.debug)
    771         try:
--> 772             run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
    773         finally:
    774             # reset the first request information if the development server

/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py in run_simple(hostname, port, application, use_reloader, use_debugger, use_evalex, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type, threaded, processes, request_handler, static_files, passthrough_errors, ssl_context)
    687         from ._reloader import run_with_reloader
    688         run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval,
--> 689                           reloader_type)
    690     else:
    691         inner()

/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py in run_with_reloader(main_func, extra_files, interval, reloader_type)
    248             reloader.run()
    249         else:
--> 250             sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
    251     except KeyboardInterrupt:
    252         pass

SystemExit: 1
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're using Jupyter Notebook or IPython to run the development server. You've also enabled debug mode, which enables the reloader by default. The reloader tries to restart the process, which IPython can't handle.

Preferably, use the `flask` command to run the development server.

```
export FLASK_APP=my_app.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run
```

Or use the plain `python` interpreter to run the application if you still want to use `app.run`, which is no longer recommended.

```
python my_app.py
```

Or disable the reloader if you want to call `app.run` from Jupyter.

```
app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

In Visual Studio Code, to setup `flask run` in the launcher (instead of launch python), use this configuration in *.vscode/launch.json*:

```json
    {
      "name": "Python: Flask",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "flask",
      "env": { "FLASK_APP": "my_app.py", "FLASK_ENV": "development" },
      "args": ["run"],
      "args_": ["run", "--no-debugger"],      
      "jinja": true
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this one, it works perfectly fine for me:

app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)

Comment: But in this way you have to restart the (debug) app every time you made a change instead of simply reload the page (because of use_reloader=False).   At least this is the behavior in VS Code.

Comment: @Alex75 Yes, you're right. This is the behavior in Spyder too. I still don't know how to use `debug=True` and not get the `SystemExit: 1` error. Using `use_realoder=False` removes the error, but we fall in the problem you have commented.

Answer (score -1):

I was also having the same problem which got resolved by removing `debug=True`. Here's My Code

```
from flask import Flask

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def home():
    return "Homepage Here"

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside Google Colab, use this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello(): return "Hello World"

import portpicker
port = portpicker.pick_unused_port()
from google.colab import output
output.serve_kernel_port_as_window(port)

from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
host='localhost'
app_server = WSGIServer((host, port), app)
app_server.serve_forever()
```

Some explanations:

- portpicker - just to select randon free port
- serve_kernel_port_as_window - like a proxy from localhost to external access link that will be printed on output. Will may prefer to use `output.serve_kernel_port_as_iframe(port)` to show in a iframe
- gevent.pywsgi - just simple WSGIServer